# Full Screen View Hiding Navigation and Tab bar iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a Navigation Controller (say navC) and I have pushed a tabbar controller (say tabC) in navC . In the tabC I have a view controller (say viewC). Now my task is to make the viewC fullscreen on tap. but some how while resizing view, the area where the tabbar is present, is never occupied and I get a blank at the place where tabbar is present on hidding it.

Comment: did you use this self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

Answer (score 1):

Implement this in When tapped

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (appDelegate.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
{
  CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
  [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
  [[self.view.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
[appDelegate.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

 }
    if (appDelegate.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == YES)
    {

  CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
  [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
  [[self.view.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[appDelegate.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,368);
 }   
 }
```

You have to add QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put some code I could offer more accurate help, but with what I understand you need to hide the `navigationBar` of the `navigationController`. This way the `navigationController` itself is completely hidden but you can still access it to push and pop viewControllers as you are already doing.

```
self.navigationController    = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

hope this helps...